# how to call a method in controller onclick of a button and pass a variable to the same method in controller?

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to call a method in my controller onclick of a button and pass a variable to the same method, am doing this with ajax like this

```
<c:url var="searchUrl" value="/servlet/mycontroller/searchmethod" />

$(document).ready(function()
     {
 $('#submit_btn').click(function(){
var dt = $('#search_data').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "${searchUrl}/" + dt

});
});
});

 <td width="32%" align="right"><label>
  <input type="text" name="transaction_id" id="search_data" class="fld_txt" />
</label></td>
<td width="15%" align="right"><label>
  <input type="button" class="button_grey" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Search" class="button" />
```

mycontroller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchUrl/{dt}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Dto> searchJobList(WebRequest request, @PathVariable String dt, Model model) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Retrieve Id >> "+dt);
        List<Dto> list = Service.getJobSearchList(dt);
        return list;
}
```

like this am getting the following error

```
http://localhost:8080/Sample/servlet/mycontroller/searchmethod/123(dt var value)
```

how do I call my search method in the controller and pass the textbox value to this?? I need to display the list based on this dt ? Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `request mapping` this way

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/servlet/mycontroller/searchmethod/{dt}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

`searchUrl` is java script variable. on controller side you will need to map `actual URL`.

So your final code will look like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/servlet/mycontroller/searchmethod/{dt}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Dto> searchJobList(WebRequest request, @PathVariable String dt, Model model) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Retrieve Id >> "+dt);
        List<Dto> list = Service.getJobSearchList(dt);
        return list;
}
```

As mentioned in comment you have web.xml mapping as

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

So you should add request Mapping as below (Note `/servlet` will be taken care by `web.xml`
)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/mycontroller/searchmethod/{dt}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: check for case sensativity in URL

Comment: or show how you mapped the `DispatcherServlet` in your `web.xml`

Comment: my web.xml <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Is anything am missing or wrong, I checked the url, it's correct. I gave the alert, I can see the url and the value